# Why is this an incorrect sketch for the curve $(2x^2 - x +5 ) /( x^2 -1 )$

Tags: functions, polynomials, graphing-functions, curves

The asymptotes are $x=\pm1$ and $y=2$. The curve intersects the horizontal asymptote at $x=7$. It intersects with the y-axis at $y=-5$. It has two turning points at $x  \approx 0.1$ and $13.9$. Here is the sketch I made. However, plotting the graph with a graph plotter does not show the turning point on the right-most branch. Is this because I haven't 'zoomed enough', or is it something else?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZuKs.png

Comment: You state that a turning point is at $x=13.9$, but you drew the minimum at $x=7$?  Also, what range are you looking at for the plotter?  Is this an online plotter (if so, can you provide a link)?

Comment: Sorry, mistake on my part. I'll fix that. And I just googled the equation of my curve. The range can be extended by moving your mouse to the sides.

Comment: Plot your function for $7 <x <15$ and 0 <y <2$.

Comment: Looking at the google plot, it looks like the minimum is just really, really flat.

Comment: Even if I zoom in, I don't see anything there..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting this into Wolfy,
it looks like 
your sketch is correct.

That min on the right
is at
$7+4\sqrt{3}
\approx 13.928
$,
with a value of
$2\sqrt{3}-\frac32
\approx 1.9641
$
so you may not have gone
out far enough.

Comment: Could you link me to the plot? Google doesn't show the turning point..

Comment: Go to https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(2x%5E2+-+x+%2B5+)+%2F(+x%5E2+-1+)

Comment: Oh, I think I see it. Thanks.